# Pushing to an array that supplies data to a component builder

Tags: javascript, arrays, components

In building out components, I used a function to append articles to a page. The functional components draws from an array of objects called data. I tried to use .push() to add an additional article to the array and thus, to the page. However, this did not work. When I add the article to the array manually, though it works. What am I doing wrong as far as .push()?

Here is part of the array:

```
let data = [
  {
    title: 'Lambda School Students: "We\'re the best!"',
    date: 'Nov 5th, 2018',
    firstParagraph: `Lucas ipsum dolor sit amet ben twi'lek padmé darth darth darth moff hutt organa twi'lek. Ben amidala secura skywalker lando
        moff wicket tatooine luke.Solo wampa wampa calrissian yoda moff.Darth grievous darth gonk darth hutt.Darth baba skywalker
        watto fett jango maul han.Mon ewok sidious sidious lando kenobi grievous gamorrean solo.Yoda wedge utapau darth calamari.
        Hutt calamari darth jabba.Darth dooku amidala organa moff.Boba darth binks solo hutt skywalker dantooine skywalker.Qui - gonn
        jar twi'lek jinn leia jango skywalker mon.`,

    secondParagraph: `Grievous fett calamari anakin skywalker hutt.Alderaan darth kenobi darth r2- d2
        windu mothma.Sidious darth calamari moff.Wampa mothma sith wedge solo mara.Darth gonk maul sith moff chewbacca palpatine
        mace amidala.C - 3po solo skywalker anakin yoda leia.Maul wampa bespin watto jade ewok darth jabba.Lando dantooine moff
        k - 3po dantooine luke.Fisto mandalore darth wedge c - 3p0 ahsoka.Secura moff palpatine fett.Anakin sith darth darth.Moff
        solo leia ben ponda jade.Binks jango aayla skywalker skywalker cade.Mustafar darth ventress anakin watto.Yavin jawa sebulba
        owen jinn tatooine sith organa.`,

    thirdParagraph: `Dagobah hutt jawa leia calamari ventress skywalker yoda. Binks wicket hutt coruscant sidious
        naboo ackbar tatooine. Hutt lars padmé darth. Maul solo darth darth jabba qui-gon chewbacca darth maul. Moff baba wicket
        han. C-3po antilles moff qui-gon ahsoka aayla dooku amidala. Palpatine droid amidala droid k-3po twi'lek padmé wookiee. Leia
        moff calamari mon obi-wan. Solo grievous lando coruscant. Jinn darth palpatine obi-wan mon.`
  },
  {
    title: 'Javascript and You, ES6',
    date: 'May 7th, 2019',
    firstParagraph: `Alohamora wand elf parchment, Wingardium Leviosa hippogriff, house dementors betrayal. Holly, Snape centaur portkey ghost
        Hermione spell bezoar Scabbers. Peruvian-Night-Powder werewolf, Dobby pear-tickle half-moon-glasses, Knight-Bus. Padfoot
        snargaluff seeker: Hagrid broomstick mischief managed. Snitch Fluffy rock-cake, 9 ¾ dress robes I must not tell lies. Mudbloods
        yew pumpkin juice phials Ravenclaw’s Diadem 10 galleons Thieves Downfall. Ministry-of-Magic mimubulus mimbletonia Pigwidgeon
        knut phoenix feather other minister Azkaban. Hedwig Daily Prophet treacle tart full-moon Ollivanders You-Know-Who cursed.
        Fawkes maze raw-steak Voldemort Goblin Wars snitch Forbidden forest grindylows wool socks`,

    secondParagraph: `Boggarts lavender robes, Hermione Granger Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them. Bee in your bonnet Hand of Glory elder
        wand, spectacles House Cup Bertie Bott’s Every Flavor Beans Impedimenta. Stunning spells tap-dancing spider Slytherin’s Heir
        mewing kittens Remus Lupin. Palominos scarlet train black robes, Metamorphimagus Niffler dead easy second bedroom. Padma
        and Parvati Sorting Hat Minister of Magic blue turban remember my last.`,

    thirdParagraph: `Toad-like smile Flourish and Blotts he knew I’d come back Quidditch World Cup. Fat Lady baubles banana fritters fairy lights 
        Petrificus Totalus. So thirsty, deluminator firs’ years follow me 12 inches of parchment. Head Boy start-of-term banquet Cleansweep Seven 
        roaring lion hat. Unicorn blood crossbow mars is bright tonight, feast Norwegian Ridgeback. Come seek us where our voices sound, we cannot 
        sing above the ground, Ginny Weasley bright red. Fanged frisbees, phoenix tears good clean match.`
  },
];
```

Here is the code I used to try to push to it:

```
let addedArticle = {
  title: 'This week\'s sprint: I\'m scared!',
  date: 'October 31, 2019',
  firstParagraph: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.',
  secondParagraph: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.',
  thirdParagraph: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.'
}

data.push(addedArticle);
```

Comment: have you tried to reload the page after adding this new post?

Comment: I've tried reloading. I've also tried opening the page using ctrl + B in VS Code. Neither worked. It's the code that's not working, not a refresh issue. @phalanx